# How to test a DNS connection? Just as the button "Test" in the ODBC Data Source Administrator?

Tags: c#, dns, odbc

[image: Print showing the button that makes the connection test]

I wonder how to write code in C# to simulate the button shown in the above image.

Any help is welcome.

Comment: I would create an [OdbcConnection](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.odbc.odbcconnection(v=vs.110).aspx) then call [Open()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.odbc.odbcconnection.open(v=vs.110).aspx) and catch any exceptions.

Answer (score 1):

Check this out. You can add below code in your form application on button click event.

```
string sqlConn = "Data Source=YOURSERVERNAME;Initial Catalog=DBNAME;User ID=DBUSER;Password=DBUSERPWS;Application Name=MyTestApp;"
//For port number
//string sqlConn = "Data Source=YOURSERVERNAME,5432;Initial Catalog=DBNAME;User ID=DBUSER;Password=DBUSERPWS;Application Name=MyTestApp;"

SqlConnection myConnection = new SqlConnection(sqlConn);

try
{
    myConnection.Open();
    MessageBox.Show("Connected successfully");              

}
catch(Exception e)
{

    MessageBox.Show("Error. Error Message:" + ex.Message);

}
```

Comment: I forgot to mention that the test is specific to PostgreSQL. Using the SqlConnection did not work, but I used the "Npgsql" and the class "NpgsqlConnection" managed to reach the desired goal!